# Using Osgeo4w shell via. python script

Tags: python, shell, osgeo, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to write a script that creates multiple ogr2ogr calls to a WFS service (in a loop). For some reason i can't use the osgeo lib (it's a work computer, with limited access..), so i figured i would give the Subprocess lib a try.

My though process so far is:

- open OSGeo4W shell
- transfer string from script to shell command line
- loop for multiple ogr2ogr calls

Code:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\OSGeo4W.bat',
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

call = 'ogr2ogr -f "CSV" "folder_on_pc" WFS:"dbname" -sql "SELECT * from 
specific_layer where attribute>=20180311 ORDER BY attribute"'

subprocess.check_call(call, shell=True)
output = p.communicate(call)[0]
```

I know the ogr2ogr call works, but can't seem to make the command line 'type it'. If this is a completly wrong approach, please tell me. I appriciate all help.